# Making certain specializations of a function template friend

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, friend

Suppose I have

```
template<class T>
void f(T t);
```

and

```
template<class T>
class X
{   
};
```

If I want only `f<T>` to be friend of `X<T>`,  I declare:

```
template<class T>
class X
{
    friend void f<>(T t);
};
```

Now suppose f is declared like this:

```
template<class T, class U>
void f(T t, U u);
```

I want to declare the following: for any type `U` `f<T, U>` is friend of `X<T>`. So I want `f<int, char>` to be friend of `X<int>`, but I don't want `f<char, int>` to be frient of `X<int>`. Is this possible? The following doesn't seem to compile

```
template<class T>
class X
{
    template <class U>  
    friend void f<>(T t, U, u);
};
```

Please note that I'm aware how to declare the whole template as friend.

Comment: That would involve a partial function template specialization of some kind. And since those are not allowed, I doubt this is possible.

Comment: @jrok: That's my suspicion so far. But C++ is full of surprises. I'm hoping someone would come up with the right syntax or prove (by standard) that it's impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is no way in current C++ to do what I'm after.

Answer (score -2):

[EDIT]
I had taken this idea from a [website](http://www.devx.com/cplus/10MinuteSolution/30302/0/page/4) which stated this was possible,
but not properly tested it. As it turns out, this does not work,
so please disregard this suggestion.

As far as I can tell, what OP wants to do is not possible in c++...
[/EDIT]

The code as you posted it would partially specialize the function f, however this is not allowed.

To fix it, remove the empty angle brackets from the friend declaration:

```
template<class T>
class X
{
    template <class U>  
    friend void f(T t, U, u);
};
```

Comment: The only way to get a declaration of `f` in namespace scope in this case is to instantiate some X. That's not what OP wants, I believe.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. He just wants to restrict the possible instantiations of f that can be friends of X, depending on the template parameter of X, right? That's what this does. Of course you need to instantiate X to actually know which functions f apply, I thought that was given.

Comment: In OP `f` is already declared in namespace scope. As I understand, they don't wan't to limit to only certain specializations, but just want to befriend some of them. Now, given that, when you instantiate some `X`, you get *another* overload of `f` in namespace scope and the results can be a bit surprising depending on how and where we instantiate X. Take [this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=21f5a1042a9e66a5e482593a56c76215-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51) for example. Now try to uncomment `X<int> x;` and try again. The output differs.

Comment: [Or this one.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0ab181b7034b37a4947de9c8b8052520-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51)

Comment: Interesting. Note that this doesn't happen when compiling with clang. Also, you're defining the function you want to befriend within the class, which I don't think OP wanted to do, in which case it's fine, but I see your point, that is troublesome. Is it normal that you can access the specialized version of f from global scope, even though it isn't declared in global scope? I've never seen this before..

Comment: I mean if you define f outside of X, you can still declare it a friend of X this way, and access the function even if no X has been instantiated, right?